# mvc2 with oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

i don't know how to start my application and where to start.If you guys having any sample application from these technologies, please share it (or) kindly guide me to start my application. my technologies Framework 3.5 and language will be c# and template will be MVC2 and back-end will be oracle 9i.Already i have a database & tables.

Answer (score 2):

You should really not be mixing ASP.NET MVC with some specific data access technology. You should abstract it away into a DAL layer. For example:

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{
    Product Get(int id);
}
```

and then a controller:

```
public class ProductsController: Controller
{
    private readonly IProductsRepository _repository;
    public ProductsController(IProductsRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var product = _repository.Get(id);
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

then you could have an implementation of this products repository which will be specific to an Oracle database:

```
public class ProductsRepositoryOracle: IProductsRepository
{
    ... Oracle specific data access code
    you could either use an ORM such as NHibernate, EF, ... or
    plain ADO.NET with the ODP.NET provider. It's really an implementation
    detail that has no impact on the MVC application.
}
```

Then all that's left is to configure your DI framework to pass the Oracle repository implementation into the controller.

This way you have your ASP.NET MVC application is totally decoupled from the place where the data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way for you would be using Entity Framework model. It will add the necessary abstraction layer Darin mentioned. In order to be able to use Oracle as an underlying database server you may need to install Entity Framework provider if you have no one yet (check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html).

Check these tutorial, which no doubt will be useful for you:
[Creating Model Classes with the Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs)